# Constructing bounded function from an unbounded function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

**Setting**: 
Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue measurable set such that $\lambda(A)<\infty$ and $f:A\rightarrow[-\infty,\infty]$ a Lebesgue measurable function such that it is bounded almost everywhere in $A$.

**Problem**: 
Construct bounded Lebesgue measurable function $g:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall \epsilon >0$ it holds

$$\lambda (\{x\in A | f(x)\not= g(x)\})< \epsilon$$

**My efforts**: 
I understand that $g$ should somehow mimic $f$ in most of the points in $A$, but I can't figure out how to deal with the "bad" points. Could someone help me where to start and what to look for?

Comment: What definition of "bounded almost everywhere" are you using?